# IAR Dependency graph

Tags: arm, iar, dependency-graph

I'm using IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM Cortex-M3 programming. The library I have to use is huge and I need a dependency graph to understand some parts. Can IAR create it or give me a useful report from a compiled code?

Thanks

Behnam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried giving the --dependencies option directly to the IAR compiler?

You should be able to take that output and use it to generate a dependency graph with, say, graphviz. If you use the --dependencies=m variant, then you will get a makefile-like output which will give you each header file required by each object file.

The IAR compiler manual is [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEEQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.efo.ru%2Fdoc%2FAtmel%2Fpdf%2FEWARM_CompilerReference.pdf&ei=bPZUVcTRDo2f7gat1oC4Aw&usg=AFQjCNFL2lsFRd3JiavVp7l1o-k6paGa7Q&sig2=hcuEinmAMCHESIkm0KVoGw&bvm=bv.93112503,d.ZGU&cad=rja); --dependencies is described on p 132

There's also [makegrapher](https://code.google.com/p/makegrapher/), which, if not exactly what you're after might be a good starting point :D

(Please excuse the delay in reply - I actually found your question while searching for answers to my own about using --dependencies!)

Comment: I'm going to check your solution, thank you so much for answering :)

Comment: While digging for another option yesterday, I also noticed the `--header_context` option which "Lists all referred source files"...might be of use.